# Duplicate ID on Tree (Primefaces 5.2 & Liferay 6.2)

Tags: primefaces, liferay, jboss-eap-6

I cannot use primefaces tree component in liferay and I don't understand why.
I tried a lot of hack (scope, UiTreeNode/TreeNode, without node, ...) but I always got a duplicate Id when I submit/refresh my page (ajax or non-ajax).

I have no other ideas so I came to you...

xhtml :

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

java :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "treeBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable
{

    private TreeNode root;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

        node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
        node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
        node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
        root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you written? Can you explain better what is the problem?

Comment: I updated primefaces from 5.1 to 5.2.13 (Elite) then the page which contains a tree doesn't work anymore. So, on an other page, I copy the primefaces showcase tree code example but it failed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found. Maybe I can help somebody.

You have to know that liferay bridge is certified for Primefaces major version, not Elite version. But the patch 5.2.4 changed the implementation of UITree#visitTree and it seems that the bridge cannot handle this modification. I don't know why but it cannot. So I override some method (visitTree/visitFacets/visitNodes) in order to ignore the improvement about a boolean related to visited nodes (to be honest, I don't really understand). Aaaaand it works ! Q.E.D

https://www.liferay.com/fr/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-4-x-3-x-2-x-ga6-released